# PHP LOOP from database and save into one field

Tags: php, arrays, loops, field

I need some help.

I have table one with field code and table two with field code_two.

record from table_one :

```
----code----
32
23
34
25
------------
```

and send to table_two like this

```
----code_two-----
32,23,34,25.
-----------------
```

I want to send record from table **one** field 'code' into table **two** field code_two.

Here my php loop input box

```
foreach($_POST['code'] as $cnt => $qty) {|
    mysql_query("insert into table_two values('$code_from_table_one');
}
```

is that loop in query is work? I tried and getting error, little help please.

Comment: You could take all the values from the first query into an array and use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function, that way you only need to run one insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to use PHP for it you can do it with GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO code_two SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`code` SEPARATOR ',') FROM code
```

More on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: simple solutions are the best :) my friend